# Sed is ignoring sinqle quotes when adding lines to a file

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, bash, sed

I want to add some PHP code to my Wordpress `wp-config.php` file using sed. But while adding, sed ignore `'` from the text that I'm adding.

I want to add these lines

```
if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    $forwarded_ips = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] );
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $forwarded_ips[0];
    unset( $forwarded_ips );
}
```

after start of the `php` tag.

This is the sed command I'm using:

```
sed -i '/<?php/a "if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {\n\t$forwarded_ips = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] );\n\t$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $forwarded_ips[0];\n\tunset( $forwarded_ips );\n}"' wp-config.php
```

Everything is going perfectly, but sed ignores the single quotes, `'`.

My output looks as below:

```
if ( !empty( $_SERVER[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] ) ) {
        $forwarded_ips = explode( ,, $_SERVER[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] );
        $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] = $forwarded_ips[0];
        unset( $forwarded_ips );
}
```

But I want some thing like below:

```
if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    $forwarded_ips = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] );
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $forwarded_ips[0];
    unset( $forwarded_ips );
}
```

Sed is ignoring the character `'` and adding a blank space for that character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having a problem is that you're using single quotes around the sed command and also inside the string that you're trying to insert. This means that what you have is the first part of your command in single quotes, followed by a string `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` outside of quotes, etc.

Try this instead:

```
sed -i -f script.sed wp-config.php
```

Where `script.sed` contains the following:

```
/<?php/a\
if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {\
    $forwarded_ips = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] );\
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $forwarded_ips[0];\
    unset( $forwarded_ips );\
}
```

Using a script file means that you don't need to worry about using quotes in the sed command. It also allows you to write out the text you intend to append more clearly - the only thing you need to remember is to add `\` at the end of each line in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using the `r` command to read in a file:

Our PHP file, `test.php`, looks like this:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World";
    echo "\n";
?>
```

We can put the complete content of what should be included, verbatim, into a separate file, `insert`:

```
if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    $forwarded_ips = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] );
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $forwarded_ips[0];
    unset( $forwarded_ips );
}
```

The `r` command takes a file name as an argument and prints its contents at the end of the current cycle, taking care of any quoting and special character issues:

```
$ sed '/<?php/r insert' test.php
<?php
if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    $forwarded_ips = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] );
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $forwarded_ips[0];
    unset( $forwarded_ips );
}
    echo "Hello World";
    echo "\n";
?>
```

To fix indentation, we could just indent the code in `insert` correspondingly.